# "wrong element type" when using JSONBArray using pgx

Tags: arrays, postgresql, go, jsonb, pgx

I am trying to insert a new row that has an `inventory` with data type `jsonb[]`:

```golang
elements := []pgtype.Text{{String: `{"adsda": "asdasd"}`, Status: pgtype.Present}}
dimensions := []pgtype.ArrayDimension{{Length: 1, LowerBound: 1}}
inventory := pgtype.JSONBArray{Elements: elements, Dimensions: dimensions, Status: pgtype.Present}
row = db.pool.QueryRow(context.Background(), `INSERT INTO user ("email", "password", "inventory") VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING uuid, email, "password"`, requestEmail, requestPassword, inventory)
```

But I get the following error:

```
"Severity": "ERROR",
"Code": "42804",
"Message": "wrong element type",
"Detail": "",
"Hint": "",
"Position": 0,
"InternalPosition": 0,
"InternalQuery": "",
"Where": "",
"SchemaName": "",
"TableName": "",
"ColumnName": "",
"DataTypeName": "",
"ConstraintName": "",
"File": "arrayfuncs.c",
"Line": 1316,
"Routine": "array_recv"
```

Postgres table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.user (
    uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    email varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    inventory _jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);
```

What might be the issue? Any idea would help.

Comment: You may want to open an issue on `pgtype`'s github page. Not that I know how that package works exactly, but at a glance [this](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/jsonb_array.go#L416-L417) seems to me like it *could* be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Type `jsonb[]` in pgx was broken

As for the error message you report:

```
"Severity": "ERROR",
"Code": "42804",
"Message": "wrong element type",
...
```

The [Guthub page on pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) reveals:

> The binary format can be substantially faster, which is what the pgx interface uses.

So you are using the binary protocol. For this, the data types have to use a compatible binary format, and it seems that `ARRAY of jsonb` is not encoded properly? Related:

- [PostgreSQL/PostGIS - PQexecParams - wrong element type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810422/postgresql-postgis-pqexecparams-wrong-element-type)

Luckily for you, the author seems to have [**fixed this just yesterday**](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/jsonb_array_test.go): (!)

> jackc: Fix JSONBArray to have elements of JSONB

Your problem should go away once you install the latest version containing commit 79b05217d14ece98b13c69ba3358b47248ab4bbc

#### `jsonb[]` vs. `jsonb` with nested JSON array

It might be simpler to use a plain `jsonb` instead of `jsonb[]`. JSON can nest arrays by itself. Consider:

```sql
SELECT '[{"id": 1}
       , {"txt": "something"}]'::jsonb  AS jsonb_array
     , '{"{\"id\": 1}"
        ,"{\"txt\": \"something\"}"}'::jsonb[] AS pg_array_of_jsonb;
```

Either can be unnested in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[{"id": 1}, {"txt": "something"}]'::jsonb) AS jsonb_element_from_json_array;

SELECT unnest('{"{\"id\": 1}","{\"txt\": \"something\"}"}'::jsonb[]) AS jsonb_element_from_pg_array;
```

Same result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ecfa7cef8f685bca7d4268790169eed5)*

That should also avoid your error.

#### Additional error

Your `INSERT` command:

```
INSERT INTO user ("email", "password", "inventory") VALUES ...
```

... should really raise this:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"

Because `user` is a [**reserved word**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You would have to double-quote it to make it work. But rather don't use `user` it as Postgres identifier. Ever.

The table creation works because there the tablename is schema-qualified, which makes it unambiguous:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user ( ...
```